# Spark Scala Dataset map works in main but not in function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, implicit

I've got 2 datasets:

```
implicit val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("app").master("local[1]")
  .config("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
  .getOrCreate()


import spark.implicits._
val ds1 = /*read csv file*/.as[caseClass1]   
val ds2 = /*read csv file*/.as[caseClass2]
```

Then I do join and map like:

```
  val ds3 = ds1.
  joinWith(ds2, ds1("id") === ds2("id"))
  .map{case(left, right) => (left, Option(right))}
```

Getting expected result.

The problem is that i'm trying to implement RichDataset with that and some other functions like following:

```
object Extentions {

  implicit class RichDataset[T <: Product](leftDs: Dataset[T]) {

    def leftJoinWith[V <: Product](rightDs: Dataset[V], condition: 
Column)(implicit spark: SparkSession) : Dataset[(T, Option[V])] = {
      import spark.implicits._

      leftDs.joinWith(rightDs, condition, "left")
        .map{case(left, right) => (left, Option(right))}
    }
  }
 }
```

In main, with  import Extentions._ call to leftJoinWith fails:

`Error:(15, 13) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
        .map{case(left, right) => (left, Option(right))}`

`Error:(15, 13) not enough arguments for method map: (implicit evidence$6: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[(T, Option[V])])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[(T, Option[V])].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$6.
        .map{case(left, right) => (left, Option(right))}`

... But spark.implicits._ are imported inside the function!

If return just join, not the join + map, it will work both in main and in function.

*scalaVersion := "2.11.8", sparkVersion := "2.2.0"*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `TypeTag` to the generic type argument, it works (saw this in Spark's source-code):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, Dataset, SparkSession}


object Extentions {

  implicit class RichDataset[T <: Product : TypeTag](leftDs: Dataset[T]) {

    def leftJoinWith[V <: Product : TypeTag](rightDs: Dataset[V], condition:
    Column)(implicit spark: SparkSession) : Dataset[(T, Option[V])] = {
      import spark.implicits._

      leftDs.joinWith(rightDs, condition, "left")
        .map{case(left, right) => (left, Option(right))}
    }
  }
}
```